# Extract number between two characters in Hive SQL

Tags: sql, regex, hive, hiveql, numeric

The query below outputs `1642575.0`. But I only want `1642575` (just the number without the decimal and the zero following it). The number of delimited values in the field varies. The only constant is that there's always only one number with a decimal. I was trying to write a regexp function to extract the number between `"` and `.`.

How would I revise my regexp_extract function to get the desired output? Thank you!

`select regexp_extract('{"1244644": "1642575.0", "1338410": "1650435"}','([1-9][0-9]*[.][0-9]+)&*');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the result to `bigint`.

```
select cast(regexp_extract('{"1244644": "1642575.9", "1338410": "1650435"}','([1-9][0-9]*[.][0-9]+)&*') as bigint) col;
output - 1642575
```

You can use round if you want to round it off.

```
select round(regexp_extract('{"1244644": "1642575.9", "1338410": "1650435"}','([1-9][0-9]*[.][0-9]+)&*')) col;
output - 1642576
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regexp: `'"(\\d+)\\.'`  - means double-quote, capturing group with one or more digits, dot.

```
select regexp_extract('{"1244644": "1642575.9", "1338410": "1650435"}','"(\\d+)\\.',1)
```

Result:

```
1642575
```

To skip any number of leading zeroes, use this regexp: `'"0*(\\d+)\\.'`